# MySQL Query Optimization for query with many JOINS

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I have the following query that takes more than 5 minutes to be executed.
Do you have any suggestions to be optimized and run faster?

```
SELECT if(ppa.id_product_attribute>0,CONCAT_WS('',ppl.name,' : ',pal.name), ppl.name) as PName, psp.visibility, psp.id_supplier, psp.id_manufacturer, psa.out_of_stock, psp.id_category_default, psp.id_tax_rules_group, if(ppa.id_product_attribute>0,CONCAT_WS('',psp.id_product,'-',ppa.id_product_attribute), psp.id_product) as PKey, if(ptswad.id_tot_switch_attribute_disabled>0 OR psp.active=0,0,1) as PActive, if(ppa.weight>0, psp.weight+ppa.weight, psp.weight) as PWeight, if(ppa.ean13>0, ppa.ean13, psp.ean13) as PBarcode,if(ppa.reference!='', ppa.reference, psp.reference) as PReference, es.s1_supplier_key as PSupplierKey, ep.s1_product_key as S1Key
FROM ps_product psp
LEFT JOIN ps_stock_available psa ON psa.id_product=psp.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute ppa on ppa.id_product=psp.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_tot_switch_attribute_disabled ptswad on ptswad.id_product_attribute=ppa.id_product_attribute
LEFT JOIN ps_product_lang ppl on ppl.id_product=psp.id_product
LEFT JOIN ps_product_attribute_combination ppac on ppac.id_product_attribute=ppa.id_product_attribute
LEFT JOIN ps_attribute_lang pal on pal.id_attribute=ppac.id_attribute and pal.id_lang=2
LEFT JOIN erp_suppliers es on es.ps_supplier_id=psp.id_supplier
LEFT JOIN erp_products ep on ep.ps_product_id=if(ppa.id_product_attribute>0,CONCAT_WS('',psp.id_product,'-',ppa.id_product_attribute), psp.id_product)
WHERE ppl.id_lang=2 AND ppl.id_shop=1 AND psp.active=1
GROUP BY PKey
LIMIT 500,600
```

**UPDATE 1**

The main table (ps_product) has more than 12.000 records

I think if there is any optimization on query structure I can make and also which indexes I should create?

**UPDATE 2**

Find below the EXPLAIN query
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Would you provide more information about your table structure and the amount of data you are searching?

Comment: And `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: I just updated my first post with explain detailed

Comment: @ChrisEl Are you still looking for solutions or is this abandoned?

Answer (score -1):

Finally, I didn't find any optimization in the query, but I realized that LIMIT 500,600 it needs the same time compared to 500,2500
So I reduced the loop circles and the total exec time reduced too